# Add controls to a c# user control at runtime and be able to manage them

Tags: c#, user-interface, user-controls

1)
I develop a c# user control.
In that control, I have a button. When the user clicks the button at runtime, a new control (for example, pictureBox) is created ,next to the previous pictureBox.

I did it that way:

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.Location = new Point(oldPb.X, oldPb.Y + 100);
pb.Size = oldPb.Size;
Controls.Add(pb);
```

The problem is, that I want to be able to manage all of the created items.
I want, for example, to index the pictureBoxes, then get a number from the user and change the photo of the wanted photoBox.
for example:

```
photoBox3.Image = .......
```

How can I do it?

2)
I want to be able to recognize when the user clicks on one of those photoBoxes and do an action on the chosen photoBox.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Tag` Property of the PictureBox to store some kind of index.

You can then have all your PictureBoxes respond to a click event:

`pb.Click += new EventHandler(picturebox_Click);`

and check the Tag there

```
private void picturebox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
   if (pb != null)
   {
     string s = pb.Tag
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Location = new Point(.....);
    pb.Size = ......;
    pb.Click += pb_Click;
    Controls.Add(pb);
    pictureBoxes.Add(pb);
}

pictureBoxes[3].Image=..... //Use like this
```

---

```
void pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
    //Do work
}
```